# jenkins-job-builder generates wrong xml when using credentials plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

We are using jenkins-job-builder in order to generate jenkins jobs, and we have an ongoing issue when we try to user ssh-credentials plug-in.
When we create a new job which tries to use an ssh key the job fails with
`java.io.IOException: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials` but if we hit `Configure` and `Save` it starts working.

In the credentials.xml the key definition looks like this:

```xml
 <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey plugin="ssh-credentials@1.15">
          <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
          <id>jenkins-key</id>
          <description>Jenkins user private key</description>
          <username>root</username>
          <privateKeySource class="com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource">
            <privateKey>{A_WORKING_PRIVATE_KEY}</privateKey>
          </privateKeySource>
   </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
```

Regarding the documentation (https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/wrappers.html?highlight=credentials#wrappers.ssh-agent-credentials) a job definition which uses the defined credential should look like this:

```
- wrapper:
    name: jenkins-key
    wrappers:
      - ssh-agent-credentials:
          user: 'root'

[...]

- job:
    name: jobxyz
    disabled: false
    project-type: freestyle
    node: jenkins-slave
    wrappers:
        - jenkins-key
    builders:
      - shell: |
          [...]
```

The corresponding part from the generated jobs xml looks like this:

```xml
   <buildWrappers>
      <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper>
        <user>root</user>
        <ignoreMissing>false</ignoreMissing>
      </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper>
    </buildWrappers>
```

But when we try to run the job we get the above mentioned error :

```java
FATAL: 
java.io.IOException: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.preCheckout(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:209)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.preCheckout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:76)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:498)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
FATAL: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
java.io.IOException: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.preCheckout(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:209)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.preCheckout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:76)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:498)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

If we go to the jenkins webpage, and hit `configure & save` without changing anything in the configuration, the new xml for the job changes to:

```xml
  <buildWrappers>
      <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper plugin="ssh-agent@1.17">
        <credentialIds>
          <string>jenkins-key</string>
        </credentialIds>
        <ignoreMissing>false</ignoreMissing>
      </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper>
    </buildWrappers>
```

I am pretty sure that this shouldn't work like this, but I am a bit uncertain about what to do next.
Here are some versions:

Jenkins Job Builder version: **2.10.1**

Jenkins ver. **2.172**

SSH Credentials version: **1.15**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems at the end of the day the solution is to forget using the credentials wrapper, and instert the raw xml instead:

```
wrappers:
        - raw:
            xml: |
              <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper plugin="ssh-agent@1.17">
                  <credentialIds>
                      <string>jenkins-key</string>
                  </credentialIds>
                  <ignoreMissing>false</ignoreMissing>
              </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper>
```

This generates correct xml.